# How to pass sessionStorage via headers using async await with graphql mutations

Tags: async-await, graphql, header, react-apollo, session-storage

I need to pass the sessionStorage dynamically through apollo client via graphql Mutations
but we use async/await to use graphql mutations, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can take sessionStorage and assign it to a variable then use Mutations to call the API with the variables passed in

Ex:

```
const [sendEmail] = useMutation(SEND_EMAIL);

const sendMail = await sendEmail({ variables: { to, subject, body } });
```

don't forget to import :

```
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
```